# A query works in SQL*Plus but fails in JDBC with an ORA-00911 exception

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to track the amount of redo being generated during a database session with the following query:

```
SELECT a.name, b.VALUE
  FROM v$statname a, v$mystat b
  WHERE a.statistic# = b.statistic# AND a.name = 'redo size';
```

This query works directly in SQL*Plus and Toad, but I get an ORA-00911 exception using JDBC, and I've narrowed it down to the "statistic#" column name.

How do I get around this?

Comment: The valid characters for an, unquoted, Oracle object (table, column etc) are `a-z`, `0-9`, `#`, `_` and `$` and must begin with `a-z`. Though you're discouraged from using `#` and `$` and I would strongly discourage you from using quoted names. Chances are the `#` is not the problem as a_horse_with_no_name says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column name `statistic#` is not the problem.

My bet is that you also send the terminating `;` from inside your Java program.

But you may not include the the `;` when executing a SQL statement through JDBC (at least not in Oracle and some other DBMS).

Remove the `;` from your SQL String and it should be fine.

Comment: Rookie error on my part.  You are right, I had the semicolon in there.  Removing it fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

put it in double quotes - that should let you call  a field anything in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Switch on JDBC logging, check your driver documentation for how to do this. In the JDBC log you see the actual statement prepared and executed in the DB. This eliminates one possible cause for the error.